# "No calendars have been synchronized with this device."

Tags: calendar, google-pixel, 9.0-pie

I'm running Android 9 and I'm trying to add an event in Calendar. Upon  clicking the circular button with a plus sign, a message saying `No calendars have been synchronized with this device.`. I don't want to synchronize the calendar on my phone with anything, be it a Google account, my carrier, or anyone. Is there anyway around this? I never had this problem on my previous Android phone or on my Android tablet.

Comment: Which calendar app are you using: Google's, Samsung's, other OEM, other third party? On your prior devices which calendar app where you using?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Google's.

Answer (score 2):

@maleb so I have the same issue but I guess the work around is in the app setting or widget hold down the calendar icon and two options appear rather; than new event (give synch loop feedback) click new reminder and you should be able to add your event.